# Solving the functional equation $\tau \left(\frac{-1}{z}\right) = - \tau(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations, modular-forms, mobius-transformation, modular-function

> Let $\mathbb{H} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be the upper half plane. Find $\tau: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C} $, holomorphic and non-constant, satisfying $\tau \left( \frac{-1}{z} \right) = - \tau(z)$.

There is a very good answer already. But since the question was put on hold, I'll add some context. This question came up in the context of Klein's $j$ - invariant. If you change coordinates from $z \to w=z-i$ and expand in $w$, you'll see from symmetry arguments that the first two coefficients must be $0$. From this, I'm wondering if $j$ is locally the square of a coordinate around $i$. This makes sense if you look at the fundamental domain for $\mathbb{H}$ mod the $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ action, and note that $j$ defines a complex analytic structure on it.

Comment: Is there any additional condition for $\tau$? (Holomorphic, continuous...). There is a trivial solution: $\tau\equiv 0$.

Comment: $\tau$ should be Holomorphic and non-constant. I'll put that in the description now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $f$ holomorphic on the upper half-plane and let
$$\tau(z)=f(z)-f(-1/z).$$

Answer (score 1):

Letting $z = i\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ turns the functional equation into $g(x) = -g(-x)$, and the solutions to those are the functions of the form $g(x) = xh(x^2)$.

Going back to the original setting, the solutions are exactly the functions of the form $\tau(z) = \frac{i-z}{i+z} f((\frac{i-z}{i+z})^2)$ where $f$ is any holomorphic function on the unit disk.

Answer (score 1):

[EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru) is our right partner.

In fact this functional equation belongs to the form of http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe1121.pdf.

The general solution is $\tau(z)=C\left(z~,-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)$ , where $C(u,v)$ is any antisymmetric function.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$\tau'(-1/z)=-z^2\tau'(z)$$

The function $\sigma(z)=1/z$ has the following property:
$$\sigma(-1/z)=-z=-z^2\sigma(z)$$

So a solution could come from $\tau'(z)=1/z$. Then $\tau(z)=C+\log z$ where $C$ is a complex constant.

Then
$$C+\log(-1/z)=-C-\log(z)$$
$$C=-\frac{\log(z)+\log(-1/z)}2=-i\frac{\arg(z)+\pi-\arg(z)}2=-i\pi/2$$

Thus,
$$\tau(z)=-i\pi/2 + \log z=\log(-iz)$$